# One Sitemap for Multiple ccTLDs

Tags: xml, sitemap, hreflang

I have a website with multiple versions.
Each version has its own ccTLD.
Some are other languages, some are in English, but for other countries.
 
I already know how to structure my sitemap and use href lang to target languages and languages per country, but can I use one single xml sitemap to cover all my sites or do I need a separate file for each ccTLD?

Comment: I think I found my own answer.

Comment: It appears that yes, you can have multiple ccTLDs covered in one sitemap: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en

Comment: The only consideration may be the filesize of your xml file. Probably better to break it out over a few different files if it is too large.